# How to adjust this query to show average goals per game, rather than total goals scored?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select u.user_name, sum(goals) 
from ((select player1_id as player, player1_goals as goals from results       
where community_id = 16 ) 
union all (select player2_id as player, player2_goals as goals from     
results where community_id = 16 ) ) p 
join users u on p.player = u.id 
group by player order by sum(goals)
```

which produces a result such as:

```
+----------+------------+
| user_name| sum(goals) |
+----------+------------+
| Player 1 |    9       |
| Player 2 |    7       |
| Player 3 |    4       |
+----------+------------+
```

This query is based on the following:

`results` table:

```
+---------------+
| results_id    |
| community_id  | 
| player1_id    | 
| player1_goals | 
| player2_id    | 
| player2_goals |
+---------------+
```

And `users` table:

```
+---------+
|   id    |
+---------+
|user_name|
+---------+
```

My issue is as follows:

Each player in the queried table has played a different number of the games, so rather than displaying how many goals each player has scored, I want to show the average number of goals scored per game.

My desired output is:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| user_name| sum(goals) | goals per game |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| Player 1 |    9       |       1.3      |
| Player 2 |    7       |       0.9      |
| Player 3 |    4       |       0.4      |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

How can I adjust my initial query to show an average of goals per game rather than just goals scored?

Comment: what defines a game? how is 1.3, 0.9 and 0.4 calculated?

Comment: so 1.3, 0.9, 0.4 are hypothetical but they would be calculated by dividing the number of goals scored `sum(goals)` by the number of games that person has played.  Each game is defined by that players `player_id / userid` appearing as either `player1_id` or `player2_id` in the `results` table.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected output based on that in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select u.user_name,
    sum(r.goals) total_goals,
round(  sum(r.goals)/count(1), 2) avg_goals
from (select
    community_id,
    player1_id id,
    player1_goals goals
from results
union all
select
    community_id,
    player2_id,
    player2_goals
from results) r
inner join users u
on r.id = u.id
where r.community_id = 16
group by r.id, u.user_name
order by avg_goals desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just tried copy & pasting it into my SQL in phpMyAdmin and it errored, would you mind amending with the following condition added so I can test again: `WHERE community_id = 16`. Thanks

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select
    player1_id id,
    player1_goals goals,
from results
union all
selec' at line 4

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from results
union all
select
    community_id,
    player2_id,
    player2_goal' at line 8

Comment: Excellent!  Thats fixed it! Thank you! (I'll now spend some time going through working out what exactly you did!) Have a great Xmas!

Comment: If I want it to be in descending order of avg_goals do I just add DESC avg_goals to the end>?

Comment: I've just realised this is incorrect... It is reporting 1.25 and the correct result should be 2.5?

Comment: Thanks - I had added in this line to your original answer to limit to 2 decimal places - ` round(sum(r.goals)/(2 * count(1)),2) avg_goals` would you mind updating your new answer with the same? thank you